# How to make AJAX request to controller inside module?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, modules, ajax

Created a new module to receive form values and process API in Craft CMS 4. How to make an AJAX request to access a controller in my module?

- module name - `giftcard`
- controller - `GiftCardController`
- action - `processRequest`

Can someone help me on this context ?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation on controllers](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/controllers.html) has everything you need. An action path consists of the module ID, the name of the controller and the name of the action. In your case, the action path will be something like `giftcard/gift-card/process-request`. You can use that as the `action` parameter in a POST request, or you can POST directly to the action's URL (`/actions/giftcard/gift-card/process-request`, where the first segment depends on your [`actionTrigger` setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#actiontrigger)).

You can make an AJAX request to that URL using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or an HTTP library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).